# Cannot make nunit test exception to work .Using .net 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing

for whatever the reason i cannot seem to get the syntax right.
How do you make the following test work. I just have a simple method TestThrowexception and would like it to pass
what Am i doing wrong here?

```
           [TestFixture]
            public class ExceptionsTests
            {       
                [Test]
                public void When_calling_my_method_it_should_throw_an_exception()
                {
                //THIS DOES NOT WORK
                    Person person=new Person();

                    PersonException ex = Assert.Throws<PersonException>(delegate { person.ThrowPersonException(); },
                                                             Has.Property("Message").EqualTo("Test person Exception throw"));

                }
            }

            public class Person
            {
                public void ThrowException()
                {
                    throw new Exception("Test Exception thrown");
                }
                public void ThrowPersonException()
                {
                    throw new CustomerException("Test person Exception thrown");
                }


                public void ThrowArgumentException(string myParam)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Argument Exception", myParam);
                }
            }
            [Serializable]
            public class PersonException : Exception
            {

                public PersonException()
                {
                }

                public PersonException(string message)
                    : base(message)
                {
                }

                public PersonException(string message, Exception inner)
                    : base(message, inner)
                {
                }

                protected PersonException(
                    SerializationInfo info,
                    StreamingContext context)
                    : base(info, context)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the issues with the type of exception you are throwing, I would do it like this.  I think its more readable.

```
[Test]
public void When_calling_my_method_it_should_throw_an_exception()
{
    Person person=new Person();
    PersonException ex = Assert.Throws<PersonException>(delegate { person.ThrowPersonException(); });
    Assert.That(ex.Message,Is.EqualTo("Test person Exception thrown");
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the example.It was a copy and paste of another example I was trying.All works now.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You throw a `CustomerException` but expect a `PersonException`. And you try to match two different strings ("thrown" vs "throw").

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to test for exceptions is to use the ExpectedException attribute on your test method. IMO this is even more readable. All depends what works for you.

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(PersonException), ExpectedMessage = "Test person Exception thrown")]
public void When_calling_my_method_it_should_throw_an_exception()
{
    Person person=new Person();
    person.ThrowPersonException();
}
```